# How to call object of same schema in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am trying to use a object which is defined in the same schema.

```
const officeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
Employee_Info:{
   Name:{
    first: String,
    middle: String,
    last: String,
    },
   Phone_Info:{
    number : Number,
    type: String
    },
},
Employer_Info:{
    Name:{
 //I am trying to use the Name object which I defined above
   },
    Phone_Info:{
//I am trying to use the Phone_Info object which I defined above
  },
},
});
```

I want the object constraints to be used anywhere in the same schema which I defined above in the name of **Name** and **Phone_Info**

Question 1 : **Solved**

Question 2:

> How to use the Schema of one model to another model?

**EMP.ts**

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import {Schema} from 'mongoose';
const employeeSchema = new Schema({
Name:{
first: String,
middle: String,
last: String,
},
Phone_Info:{
number : Number,
type: String
}
});
const employerSchema = new Schema({
employee : employeeSchema
}); 
const Employer = mongoose.model('employer', employerSchema);
export default employer;
const Employee = mongoose.model('employee', employeeSchema); 
module.exports = employee;
```

**EMP2.ts**

```
    import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
    import {Schema} from 'mongoose';
    import Employee from './emp/models';
    import 
    const employee2Schema = new mongoose.Schema({   
    employee1: Employee;
    })
```

I want to use employeeSchema in employee1

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will have to use 2 schemas, as following:

```
const employeeSchema = new Schema({
    Name:{
    first: String,
    middle: String,
    last: String,
    },
   Phone_Info:{
    number : Number,
    type: String
    }
});


const employerSchema = new Schema({
    employee : employeeSchema
});
```

And then you can export only Employer schema.

```
const Employer = mongoose.model('employer', employerSchema);

module.exports = employer;
```

**EDIT 1:**
To use this schema in another model you just have to export that schema aswell by using

```
const Employee = mongoose.model('employee', employeeSchema); 
module.exports = employee;
```

And then you import it in other model by using *import* and you can use it as in first one

```
import employee from './model_doc_name'
```

Comment: Working , thank you. but how to hide id of the object

Comment: You will have to specify that you don't want that. In curly braces for "options/settings" you can disable it:

`const employerSchema = new Schema({
    employee : employeeSchema
},{
_id: false
}
);`

Comment: Thanks. What I have to do if I want to use this employeeSchema in another model?

Comment: No problem. You just have to export that schema aswell by using `const Employee = mongoose.model('employee', employeeSchema);

module.exports = employee;`
 And then you have to import it in other model by using `import` and you can use it

Comment: Can you post this as answer so that It will be clear and I can vote too

Comment: Can you help me with import?

Comment: Just added more explanation in original comment, hope it helps

Comment: throw new TypeError('Invalid value for schema Array path `' + prefix + key + '`');  I got this when i import

Comment: You are exporting a Mongoose model but trying to use the schema. Problem is in defining new schema in imported file

Comment: I can't help without checking the code. Post the code and I will see

Comment: I am not sure how you named your files but if you are importing and name of file is not index or its not only file in directory, you have to specify name. So when importing after /model/ you have to add name of the file